# Elegantly Adding Objects to HashMap depending on some condition within code

Tags: java, hashmap, addition

I am currently building a calendar application in Java. The route I have decided to take is to keep one calendar month view in (built in JavaFX) and change the dates. As each month generally has a different first day, the dates will have to be re-added to the calendar each time the month changes. I decided to use a Hashmap, which i add the days of the month to, depending on what the first day of the month. I can then use this Hashmap in my code to do stuff with, change Text fields in the application side etc etc.

The code I have submitted is a bare bones version of how i am adding the days to the hashmap, then printing them (to show what date they are for testing purposes).

my approach works however seems long winded, and if i had a program with say 10000 Hashmap entries, this approach would not be practical.

My question is as follows: is there a more elegant approach to adding entries to Hashmap,
where the adding of entries is dependant on some condition within the code?

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;

public class MyMonth {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        addDaysFromFirstDayOfWeek(list);

        int localcount = 1;

        Set<Integer> hashset = list.keySet();

        for (Integer key : hashset) {

            String day = list.get(key);
            System.out.println( day + " is day " + localcount + " in the month " );
            localcount ++;
        }
    }


    static int count = 1;
    static int Daysinmonth = 30;

   


    public static HashMap<Integer, String> list = new HashMap<>(Daysinmonth);



    //Week 1
    static String Monday1 = "Monday1";
    static String Tuesday1 = "Tuesday1";
    static String Wednesday1 = "Wednesday1";
    static String Thursday1 = "Thursday1";
    static String Friday1 = "Friday1";
    static String Saturday1 = "Saturday1";
    static String Sunday1 = "Sunday1";

    // Week 2
    static String Monday2 = "Monday2";
    static String Tuesday2 = "Tuesday2";
    static String Wednesday2 = "Wednesday2";
    static String Thursday2 = "Thursday2";
    static String Friday2 = "Friday2";
    static String Saturday2 = "Saturday2";
    static String Sunday2 = "Sunday2";






    static String FirstDayOfWeek = Tuesday1;





    public static void addDaysFromFirstDayOfWeek(HashMap<Integer,String> hashMap) {


        if (FirstDayOfWeek.equals(Monday1)) {
            hashMap.put(count, Monday1);
            count++;
            hashMap.put(count, Tuesday1);
            count++;
            hashMap.put(count, Wednesday1);
            count++;
            hashMap.put(count, Thursday1);
            count++;
            hashMap.put(count, Friday1);
            count++;
            hashMap.put(count, Saturday1);
            count++;
            hashMap.put(count, Sunday1);
            count++;
            addDaysToArrayList(hashMap);



        } else if (FirstDayOfWeek.equals(Tuesday1)) {
            hashMap.put(count, Tuesday1);
            count++;
            hashMap.put(count, Wednesday1);
            count++;
            hashMap.put(count, Thursday1);
            count++;
            hashMap.put(count, Friday1);
            count++;
            hashMap.put(count, Saturday1);
            count++;
            hashMap.put(count, Sunday1);
            count++;
            addDaysToArrayList(hashMap);

        } else if (FirstDayOfWeek.equals(Wednesday1)) {
            hashMap.put(count, Wednesday1);
            count++;
            hashMap.put(count, Thursday1);
            count++;
            hashMap.put(count, Friday1);
            count++;
            hashMap.put(count, Saturday1);
            count++;
            hashMap.put(count, Sunday1);
            count++;
            addDaysToArrayList(hashMap);
        } else if(FirstDayOfWeek.equals(Thursday1)){
            hashMap.put(count, Thursday1);
            count++;
            hashMap.put(count, Friday1);
            count++;
            hashMap.put(count, Saturday1);
            count++;
            hashMap.put(count, Sunday1);
            count++;
            addDaysToArrayList(hashMap);
        } else if(FirstDayOfWeek.equals(Friday1)){
            hashMap.put(count, Friday1);
            count++;
            hashMap.put(count, Saturday1);
            count++;
            hashMap.put(count, Sunday1);
            count++;
            addDaysToArrayList(hashMap);
        } else if(FirstDayOfWeek.equals(Saturday1)){
            hashMap.put(count, Saturday1);
            count++;
            hashMap.put(count, Sunday1);
            count++;
            addDaysToArrayList(hashMap);
        } else if(FirstDayOfWeek.equals(Sunday1)){
            hashMap.put(count, Sunday1);
            count++;
            addDaysToArrayList(hashMap);
        }


    }

    public static void addDaysToArrayList(HashMap<Integer,String> hashMap){

        hashMap.put(count,Monday2);
        count++;
        hashMap.put(count,Tuesday2);
        count++;
        hashMap.put(count,Wednesday2);
        count++;
        hashMap.put(count,Thursday2);
        count++;
        hashMap.put(count,Friday2);
        count++;
        hashMap.put(count,Saturday2);
        count++;
        hashMap.put(count,Sunday2);
        count++;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use streams for that job. Here is an example of method that builds a map for all month/days of a year:

```
Map<Month, Map<Integer, DayOfWeek>> getMonthDaysOfWeek(int year) {
    return EnumSet.allOf(Month.class).stream()
            .map(month -> Year.of(year).atMonth(month))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    YearMonth::getMonth, 
                    yearMonth -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, yearMonth.lengthOfMonth()).boxed()
                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), 
                                    day -> yearMonth.atDay(day).getDayOfWeek()))));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just calculate and translate days of week.

```
import java.time.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<DayOfWeek, String> frenchDayOfWeek = new HashMap<>();
        frenchDayOfWeek.put(DayOfWeek.MONDAY, "lundi");
        frenchDayOfWeek.put(DayOfWeek.TUESDAY, "mardi");
        frenchDayOfWeek.put(DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY, "mercredi");
        frenchDayOfWeek.put(DayOfWeek.THURSDAY, "jeudi");
        frenchDayOfWeek.put(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY, "vendredi");
        frenchDayOfWeek.put(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY, "samedi");
        frenchDayOfWeek.put(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY, "dimanche");
        
        LocalDate d = LocalDate.of(2020, 6, 1);
        // print days to the end of month
        do {
            String s = d.toString() + " is "
                + d.getDayOfWeek().toString()
                + "(" + frenchDayOfWeek.get(d.getDayOfWeek()) + " in french)"
                + (d.getDayOfMonth() / 7 + 1);
            System.out.println(s);
            d = d.plusDays(1);
        } while (d.getDayOfMonth() != 1);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2020-06-01 is MONDAY(lundi in french)1
2020-06-02 is TUESDAY(mardi in french)1
2020-06-03 is WEDNESDAY(mercredi in french)1
2020-06-04 is THURSDAY(jeudi in french)1
2020-06-05 is FRIDAY(vendredi in french)1
2020-06-06 is SATURDAY(samedi in french)1
2020-06-07 is SUNDAY(dimanche in french)2
2020-06-08 is MONDAY(lundi in french)2
2020-06-09 is TUESDAY(mardi in french)2
...
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for taking the time to answer. However my question regarding how to add multiple entries to Hashmaps depending on some condition, although i use days of the week in this example, im not actually trying to find a way of finding out / displaying, what day of the week it is, this is for an illustrative purposes only

Comment: @Pyson  In some situation, I would recommend you to prepare `entriesToBeMerged` as a HashMap<Integer, String> in advance and `if (someConditionIsMet) { hashMap.putAll(entriesToBeMerged); }` . Sometimes you can prepare 1000 pairs of (string expression of) condition and entries in `Map<String, Map<Integer, String>>` in advance, and, when given a condition, add proper set of entries by  `hashMap.putAll(mapOfEntriesToBeMerged.get(conditionString));` As I found it hard to understand your situation, this will be the my last suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need a map. Just query Java each time instead of looking up in your own map. It shouldn’t be expensive.

```
    Locale loc = Locale.forLanguageTag("es");
    
    int year = 2020;
    Month month = Month.JULY;

    YearMonth ym = YearMonth.of(year, month);
    int daysInMonth = ym.lengthOfMonth();
    
    for (int dayCount = 1; dayCount <= daysInMonth; dayCount++) {
        String day = ym.atDay(dayCount).getDayOfWeek()
                .getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE, loc);
        System.out.println( day + " is day " + dayCount + " in the month " );
    }
```

Output, abbreviated:

> ```
> miércoles is day 1 in the month 
> jueves is day 2 in the month 
> viernes is day 3 in the month 
> sábado is day 4 in the month 
> domingo is day 5 in the month 
> (cut)
> jueves is day 30 in the month 
> viernes is day 31 in the month
> ```

Please supply your own locale. I just took Spanish as an example to illustrate that Java knows the names of the days in all major languages.

**Tutorial link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.